# Can I recursively call a method from child to parent, using an inherited method?

Tags: php

There are lots of examples of child classes calling overridden parent methods, most commonly `parent::__construct()`.  In these cases, however, you are actually calling the parent from a concrete method in the child itself.

Is there a way that I can recursively call a method from the child to the first ancestor, using an inherited method?

If I use `parent::methodName()` in my abstract parent class it causes a fatal error saying 'Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent'.  Presumably this is because 'parent' is being evaluated relative to the abstract class itself, not the current class context.

Thanks...

Comment: How do you suppose to call a method that is not implemented(abstract)?

Comment: Thanks @Johntor, right you are.  See edits above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this? (untested)

```
foreach (get_class_parents($this) as $className) {
    (new ReflectionMethod($className, __METHOD__))->invoke($this, $args...);
}
```

I hate when I see this kinda junk in code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but:

1. The `parent` keyword is evaluated relative to the class it occurs in. If the class that you use the `parent` keyword in doesn't have a parent, it obviously won't work.
2. If you want a child to use a parent's method, simply don't override that method in the child. It does not make sense to define a method in a parent that forces the child to call the parent's method, when all you need to do is simply not override the method in the child.
3. You can force the parent's method to be "the last word" by making the method `final`, the child won't be able to override it.
4. A child cannot call a "grandparent's" method, since the child does not know, or at least has no guarantee, that its parent has a parent in turn.

In practical terms that means:

1. If you are writing a class that does not `extend` another class, it doesn't make sense to use `parent` anywhere in it.
2. If you are `extend`ing a class and are not overriding a method, the parent's method will be used automatically (it is *inherited*).
3. If you are `extend`ing a class and are overriding a method, you may call the `parent`'s method from that overridden method, which in turn *may* call its `parent`'s method etc.